# How can I add another layer / new series to a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot I can add a series to a plot with:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + geom_point()
```

How do I simply add another series, e.g. plotting the cost of rubies against diamonds.  Assuming rubies was also in the diamonds dataset.  I have tried to lay over the top another layer with the rubies data, but it just plots the rubies and not the diamonds/carat.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + geom_point() + aes(x = rubies, y = price)
```

I can see that this would be possible by melding all the data together first, ready to plot it, so maybe I should go down that route.   However, just adding another series to a plot like this seems like it should not be too hard, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
rubies  <- data.frame(carat = c(3, 4, 5), price= c(5000, 5000, 5000))

ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(data = rubies, colour = "red")
```

Comment: What if you want to add a 2nd series of points *and* a second line pertaining to those new points? For example, if you already have `ggplot(dat,aes(X,Y)) + geom_point() + geom_line()` and you want to add both a 2nd `geom_point` and a 2nd `geom_line` ?

Comment: do I have to repeat the 2nd data set and variable list for both geom objects, or is there a better way?

Comment: why does it throw an aesthetics length error when you code it like: ggplot(diamonds, aes(diamonds$carat, diamonds$price)) + 
    geom_point() + 
   geom_point(data = rubies, colour = "red")

Comment: To add a second geom_line see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5323178/2682264

Comment: @Mark simply because `diamonds` contains more rows than `rubies` The answerer shows how `rubies` is constructed in the first line, and there you can see it only contains three rows. Moreover, you shouldn't use `table$row` syntax in aesthetic mappings.