# Adding points from other dataset to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

There are already many questions about this theme, but I could not find one that answered my specific problem.

I have a `barplot` (see `testplot1` and `testplot3` below) plotting a dataset (`bardata` below) and want to add points to it from another dataset (`pointdata`). See the simplified example:

```
bardata <- data.frame(
               xname = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
               yvalue = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1), 
               colorname = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c")
               )  
pointdata <- data.frame(
                xname = c(1, 1, 3), 
                ypos = c(2, 4, 3), 
                ptyname = c("p", "q", "r")
             ) 

testplot1 <- qplot(xname, yvalue, data= bardata, stat = "identity", 
               fill= factor(colorname),  geom = "bar")
testplot2 <- testplot1 + 
                geom_point(data = pointdata, mapping = 
                  aes(x = xname, y = ypos, shape = factor(ptyname))
                )
```

Now `testplot1` works perfectly fine, but `testplot2` gives the error

> Error in factor(colorname) : object 'colorname' not found.

I do not understand why he says this, and would like to know, but this is not my main problem since there is an easy workaround, see `testplot3` below.

```
 testplot3 <- qplot(xname, yvalue, data= bardata, stat = "identity", 
                      fill= factor(bardata$colorname),  geom = "bar")
 testplot4 <- testplot3 + 
                  geom_point(data = pointdata, mapping = 
                    aes(x = xname, y = ypos, shape = factor(ptyname)))
```

Now this time the program says:

> Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the
>   dataProblems:xname, ypos, factor(ptyname).

So my question is: what does this even mean? Obviously both `aes` and the data are of length 3. The number of rows in `pointdata` is less than that in `bardata`, but that is in itself not a problem, see for instance this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2330825/2298323

So what is going on here? (And how do I get my points in my plot?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue is that you are assigning `fill = factor(colorname)`for the whole plot in your `qplot` call.

So `testplot2` will also try to map `colorname` to the `fill` aesthetic but there is no `colorname` column in the `pointdata` data.frame which is why you have this error message. If you rewrite it using `ggplot`, it looks like this :

```
ggplot(bardata, aes(xname, yvalue, fill = factor(colorname))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+ 
  geom_point(data = pointdata, 
             mapping = aes(x = xname, y = ypos, shape = factor(ptyname)))
```

What you need to do is to apply the mapping only to the `geom_bar` call, like this :

```
ggplot(bardata, aes(xname, yvalue)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = factor(colorname)))+ 
  geom_point(data = pointdata, 
             mapping = aes(x = xname, y = ypos, shape = factor(ptyname)))
```

Answer (score 11):

Yeah, sometimes ggplot error descriptions are quite difficult to understand. First note: try to avoid `qplot`, for rather complicated plots it tends to obscure things. Your code is equivalent to

```
ggplot(bardata, aes(xname, yvalue, fill = factor(colorname))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_point(data = pointdata, aes(x = xname, y = ypos, shape = factor(ptyname))

#Error in factor(colorname) : object 'colorname' not found
```

And here's the problem: when you specify `aes` mapping within `ggplot()` (or `qplot()` in your case), this setting is automatically applied to any subsequent geom. You specified `x`, `y` and `fill`. For `geom_bar`, everything is okay. For `geom_point` you override `x` and `y`, but the `fill` is still mapped to `colorname` which doesn't exist in `pointdata`, therefore the error.

If you mix several data frames, here's the recommended way to go: empty `ggplot()` plus specific `aes` for each geom.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = bardata, aes(xname, yvalue, fill = factor(colorname)), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_point(data = pointdata, aes(xname, ypos, shape = factor(ptyname)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to add inherit.aes=FALSE to the geom_point call. Then the aesthetics for the points are determined separately.