# Effective way of adding mappings to aesthetic values

Tags: r, ggplot2

An extension to [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45907614/4836511), I have generated the plot using the [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45908157/4836511) suggested by eipi10.

```
valsToKeep <- c("D_1","D_4")
n <- length(valsToKeep)
getPaletteDark = brewer.pal(8,"Dark2")
colSel <- sample(getPaletteDark,n)

ggplot(df %>% 
         mutate(Val=fct_other(Val,keep=valsToKeep)) %>% 
         arrange(Val) %>% 
         filter(!duplicated(.[,c("X","Y")])), 
       aes(X,Y,col=Val)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(colSel,"grey70")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Similarly, I have tried to change mappings to other aesthetic values such  as `alpha`, `shape`:

```
ggplot(df %>% 
         mutate(Val=fct_other(Val,keep=valsToKeep)) %>% 
         arrange(Val) %>% 
         filter(!duplicated(.[,c("X","Y")])), 
       aes(X,Y,col=Val)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(colSel,"grey70")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(rep(1,n),0.2)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(rep(16,n),1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

but, it did not fetch the desired output (decrease transparency to hollow circles for `Other` points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify `alpha=Val` & `shape=Val` in your aesthetics mapping.

I also changed the range of values for shape from `c(rep(1,n),1)` to `c(rep(1,n),2)`, so that there's difference between the first 2 values & others.

```
ggplot(df %>% 
         mutate(Val=forcats::fct_other(Val,keep=valsToKeep)) %>% 
         arrange(Val) %>% 
         filter(!duplicated(.[,c("X","Y")])), 
       aes(X,Y,col=Val,alpha=Val,shape=Val)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(colSel,"grey70")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(rep(1,n),0.2)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(rep(1,n),2)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: plot]

(For info, the original colours I used were red & blue, as sampling the dark palette returned me virtually undistinguishable dark green & dark blue...)

Comment: I want same values for shapes and alpha to the values in `Val`. The changes are only intended for `Other` points.

Comment: @Prradep edited my answer. By the way varying alpha won't hollow-ify a point. If you want solid vs hollow circles, you can use `values = c(rep(16,n),1)` in the scale_shape.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I noticed the error and applied your solution. Will edit the question now.